# Spring integration with spring boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot

hi i am a newbie and i a trying to implement spring-mqtt integration with a spring boot application following is my main class

```
package com.ehydromet.springboot;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttClient;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

import com.ehydromet.outbound.MqttClientFactoryBean;
import com.ehydromet.outbound.MqttSendingMessageHandler;

@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.ehydromet.entity"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.ehydromet"})
public class SpringBootStandAloneApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    System.out.println("hi i am servlet initializer");
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MqttConfiguration.class);

        MessageChannel messageChannel = context.getBean("messages", MessageChannel.class);
        messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Josh and Andy say hi!".getBytes()).build());
    return application.sources(SpringBootStandAloneApp.class);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi i am main function");
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootStandAloneApp.class, args);
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MqttConfiguration.class);

        MessageChannel messageChannel = context.getBean("messages", MessageChannel.class);
        messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Josh and Andy say hi!".getBytes()).build());
}
 @Configuration
    @ImportResource("simple-integration.xml")
    public static class MqttConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MqttClientFactoryBean mqttClientFactoryBean() {
            return new MqttClientFactoryBean("localhost");
        }

        @Bean
        public MqttSendingMessageHandler mqttSendingMessageHandler(IMqttClient client) {
            return new MqttSendingMessageHandler(client, "cats");
        }
    }
}
```

and below is spring-integration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:mqtt="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd ">

<int:channel id="messages"/>
<int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="mqttSendingMessageHandler" channel="messages" />
</beans>
```

and following is my project structure

[image]

and app displays the following error after publishing the message

```
15:57:57.769 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'messages', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[21], headers={timestamp=1487759277754, id=92eb12e6-58d5-1358-842f-c99046ed0879}]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-02-22 15:57:59.041  INFO 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.e.springboot.SpringBootStandAloneApp   : Starting SpringBootStandAloneApp on Ehydromet-2PC with PID 4548 (C:\Users\Ehydromet\Documents\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring-boot-jsp\WEB-INF\classes\com\ehydromet\springboot\SpringBootStandAloneApp.class started by Ehydromet in C:\SpringSource\sts-3.3.0.RELEASE)
2017-02-22 15:57:59.043  INFO 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.e.springboot.SpringBootStandAloneApp   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-02-22 15:57:59.087  INFO 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1dbf0c2: startup date [Wed Feb 22 15:57:59 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-02-22 15:58:02.368  INFO 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
2017-02-22 15:58:02.369  WARN 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
2017-02-22 15:58:02.396 ERROR 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1dbf0c2: startup date [Wed Feb 22 15:57:59 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:959) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:966) [spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]

2017-02-22 15:58:02.404 ERROR 4548 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2017-02-22 15:58:02.409 ERROR 4548 --- [ina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-boot-jsp]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-boot-jsp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2017-02-22 15:58:02.416 ERROR 4548 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322) [bootstrap.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456) [bootstrap.jar:7.0.37]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2017-02-22 15:58:02.418 ERROR 4548 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Catalina.start: 

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322) [bootstrap.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456) [bootstrap.jar:7.0.37]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2017-02-22 15:58:02.418  INFO 4548 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Server startup in 22323 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is

```
Could not open ServletContext resource [/simple-integration.xml]
```

ServletContextResources :

> interpreting relative paths within the web application root directory.

Instead use

```
 @ImportResource("classpath:simple-integration.xml")
```